# Can I use mixed shellac flakes in place of Zinsser BIN primer?

Tags: ceiling, primer

I have heavy nicotine damage on my ceilings. I want to seal the ceilings and then install a drywall ceiling just below them (with cornices) to cover up the ugly painted "popcorn" texture (I tried removing the popcorn with no luck).

To reiterate: I won't be painting over it - it will be covered over with the drywall ceiling.

Comment: why wouldn't you want to use Bullseye shellac primer?  It works great.

Comment: If a 2# cut works out cheaper, it will work.  You won't get any color hiding, as plain shellac is clear. Be sure to use dewaxed flakes.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Can I ask why I would need to use dewaxed flakes? ( I won't be painting over it - it will be covered over with the drywall ceiling.) Thanks!

Comment: I guess if I read AND understood...  You don't need dewaxed..

Comment: Thanks!! Your expertise is appreciated! I contacted the makers of BIN and they tried to say that regular shellac wouldn't work - but it seemed like they were just trying to sell their product.